# How to store xml file in sybase database

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

Can someone please tell me what datatype i should use for table schema to store an xml file in a Sybase DB (Sybase ASE 11/12/15- TDS 5.5).

I guess Image can be used but i dont think we need image supported type.  Do we have anything else?

Comment: What Sybase database product are you using, and what version? ASE? ASA? SQLAnywhere? IQ? These are important details to include in your questions.  Since you are mentioning the image datatype, I am guessing you are talking about SQLAnywhere or ASA.

Comment: Sorry for not making myself clear i am using Sybase ASE 11/12/15- TDS 5.5

Answer (score 0):

`text` `unitext` and `varchar(x)` can also be used to store large text entries.  Those may be better suited for your needs.  I would recommend you take a look at the ASE docs that talk about the cost of the various options to find the one best suited for you.

http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36271.1550/html/blocks/CJACHIAI.htm